# Is there any way to detect process_vm_readv() calls?

Tags: android, c, linux, memory

I am trying to read memory of another process with `process_vm_readv()`.

As soon as I read the value the application closes itself (it isn't crashing). Somehow the application is detecting that I'm using system calls and trying to read its memory.

I'm trying this on a x86-based Android OS(7.0) with Linux 4.4 kernel.

This function is highly undocumented, any info regarding this will be helpful.

Here is stripped down version of my actual code.

```
#include <sys/uio.h>

size_t readMem()
{
    struct iovec local[1];
    struct iovec remote[1];
    char buf1[1024*8];
    ssize_t nread;
    pid_t pid = 3627; 

    local[0].iov_base = buf1;
    local[0].iov_len = sizeof(buf1);
    remote[0].iov_base = _ADDR // i in the loop below
    remote[0].iov_len = sizeof(buf1);

    return process_vm_readv(pid, local, 2, remote, 1, 0);
}
```

To be clear, this is actually a funcion. I am calling this funcion from a loop which iterates through every memory addresses of the process.

```
for(long int i=0x7000000;!found;i+=4090)
```

Comment: As a reference, i've found two resources that could help you: a man page for the sys/uio.h headerfile and a gist at this URL: https://gist.github.com/FergusInLondon/fec6aebabc3c9e61e284983618f40730

Comment: I added the funcion which is responsible for reading process memory. To be clear, I am actually trying to reverse engineer a game. I'm using process_vm_readv() to read its memory. Somehow the game is detecting that I'm trying to read its memory. But I can't find any reference anywhere which says that this function call can be detected.

Answer (score 1):

So apparently on Linux ptrace() exists.

https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/ptrace.2.html

I stumbled upon your question and I just couldn't resist making an account and contribute some knowledge right now.

Basically you can trace system calls, and sure enough, process_vm_readv is one of them.

This basically means that a program could trace any other app's syscalls for a multitude of reasons, and of course, run system calls on their name.

This has some uses, for example, btop heavily relies on it because it's a process monitor, and of course you can kill processes with it.

This also means that process_vm_readv() is one of those syscalls according to this:

https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/syscalls.2.html

I really don't know how you could get around this, maybe run as root? I'm new to actual game cheating and I can't even figure out what to do with process_vm for now (starting out with C) but you could try running as root, as I've heard that userspace processes (such as games) don't have much freedom